# "about us", " contact" sections should be article(post) or page in the simple small Business website?

Tags: posts, pages, customization

I am new in WordPress i am rails programmer that need to do for small Business only WordPress website with : main page, about us,  contact + few articles(posts) that will be in the main page

"about us", " contact" sections should be article(post) or page in the simple small Business website?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's totally up to you to decide to put it as a post or a page. I would put it as a page though.

One important difference between them is that Pages are hierarchycal and Posts chronological. You can study each in the Codex to better decide:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

This can also be usefull:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page#Learn_How_to_Use_WordPress

Comment: what about seo?post have seo parts inside

Comment: Seo parts? Like what? I'm not an expert in SEO, but having a good <title> tag, using heading tags when required and good content is enough to get the love from search engines.

Comment: can you put in page facebook follow + twitter + google plus on the page like in the post with some plugin or should be done manually?

Comment: @Yosef, if you have specific doubts about SEO, open another Question. In summary, you'll control it with the head tags and caring about your content, as rrikesh says. Anyway, go see what a SEO master has to say about WordPress anatomy: http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/, and don't forget *the Codex is Your Friend* :) . . . . Also, this is not a support forum, please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you put about us as a page and not a post. Post is specifically for blogs and date-driven articles, whereas we use pages for important information like home, about us, contact us and services.

Comment: 'Post is specifically for blogs" was maybe true 15 years ago. if you need a 5 page site there is no difference that you can't control without the need of any plugin.